# Whitelist EC2 instances in ASG to access AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf, aws-auto-scaling

I have a `CloudFront Distribution` with `WAF`(Web Application Firewall) attached to it, to restrict public access.
I also have a fleet of EC2 instances running under an `ASG`(autoScaling Group) and I wish to whitelist the EC2 instances to access the CloudFront distribution. Is it possible to create such a configuration in my infrastructure?

Please note that the IP addresses of the EC2 instances are not fixed. They are controlled by the ASG attached. Also, the ASG is created in a public subnet.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to trigger some sort of script every time the ASG adds an instance, to add the instance's public IP to the WAF.

I would suggest moving the EC2 instances to private subnets with routes to NAT gateways, then you would only have to whitelist the Elastic-IPs of the NAT Gateway(s).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Mark-b. The second solution to introduce a NAT Gateway along with a private subnet worked for me